# Latin term for 'dramaturge' using the root 'δρᾶμα'

Tags: word-request, greek-to-latin-translation

What is the equivalent of the term "dramaturge" in (Classical) Latin using the root "δρᾶμα"? Is "scriptor dramaticus" an appropriate option? Smith & Hall provides "fabularum scriptor", but I am specifically looking for a term with the δρᾶμα root.

Comment: I'm not sure that root was used at all in Classical Latin. The native word _fabula_ was much more common.

Comment: What's the need to force that root?

Answer (score 3):

As Draconis mentioned in a comment, this isn't a common word in Classical Latin, but you get it in [Late Antique Latin](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=dramatic) enough, and enough of the Classical Latin authors we have knew Greek, that [*dramaticus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=dramatikos&la=greek#lexicon) would be recognized. If someone like Cicero came across *scriptor dramaticus*, it would make sense (given the context) that this was a playwright of dramas (though it could also mean that the writer is dramatic). It's not the normal word, but I think the translation works.